Join a table with a table-valued function in PostgREST?
I'm hoping to be able to join a table to a table-valued function in PostgREST.
I have an employees table with these fields: id, name, skills--skills is an array of the skill enumerated type.
I created a function that unnests the skills[]:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_test(emp_id INT8)
RETURNS TABLE (
    id INT8,
    skill TEXT
) AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT e.id, unnest(e.skills)::text skill
    FROM employees e
    WHERE e.id = emp_id;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

I'm able to call the function in SQL:
select  e.*,t.*
from employees e
inner join fn_test(e.id) t on e.id=t.id;

When I try to use it in a URL, v1/employees?select=*,fn_test(id), I get an error:
{
    "code": "PGRST200",
    "details": "Searched for a foreign key relationship between 'employees' and 'fn_test' in the schema 'public', but no matches were found.",
    "hint": null,
    "message": "Could not find a relationship between 'employees' and 'fn_test' in the schema cache"
}

Is this possible?

What's the result that you're expecting? Listing all employees and embedding the skills? Or listing all the skills and repeating the employee's data for each skill? Providing a JSON example would help to know which alternative you need. Checking out Computed Relationships may help you too.


Is this possible?

It's not possible to request a table and embed it with a table returning function. For example, you can't do this:
/v1/table?select=rel_function(*)

But you can do the opposite, if the returning value of the function is an existing table in the Database that has a FK relationship with the embedded resource. Like this:
/v1/rpc/rel_function?select=table()

Regarding to the query you're looking for, the embedding won't be possible since you don't have a FK in the relationship. To achieve this, you can generate a custom embedding with Computed Relationships.
Still, your query seems to be better for a VIEW like:
CREATE VIEW employees_skill AS
  SELECT id, name, unnest(skills)::text as skill
  FROM employees;

Or, if you prefer a function, return the rest of the columns of employees and you won't need the JOIN.

Providing an example in JSON form of what you need can help us give you a better example.
